# Cambio de un campo mediante Trigger

Tags: postgresql, trigger

Amigos tengo el siguiente codigo, que debe cambiar mi campo estado, pero al compilarlo no me da el resultado esperado, y tengo los datos iguales en ambos campos. (Ejemplo Valor=100, y abono=100) con estos datos se deberia disparar el trigguer.

```
    create or replace function fun_cancelar_cuenta() returns trigger as $$
    begin
    update cuentasxcobrar set estado=0 where idcuenta=new.idcuenta and valor=new.abono;
    return new;
    END
    $$ language 'plpgsql';
```

Comment: Define un poco más lo que quieres hacer y también pon el código del trigger, ahi está solo la función trigger